# Add row to the top of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's the thing, I need to put one row from other dataframe to the top of main dataframe in pandas, above first row where are columns named.

Sample :

```
      1value  2value 3value 4value 5value
acity    4       3       6      2     6
bcity    2       6       6      4     1
ccity    5       11      53     6     3
dcity    5       1       4      6     3 
gcity    6       4       2      7     4
```

And the other sample:

```
1value 2value 3value 4value 5value
 2       5       2      6     3
```

And now I need to add value of second sample to the top of first sample. Desired output:

```
        2       5       2      6     3 
      1value  2value 3value 4value 5value
acity    4       3       6      2     6
bcity    2       6       6      4     1
ccity    5       11      53     6     3
dcity    5       1       4      6     3 
gcity    6       4       2      7     4
```

And just for mention, I have about 3000 rows, and 250 columns in this Sample dataframe.

I have tried with multiindex, but doesn't working, it said : `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

TypeErrorTraceback

```
(most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-230-e17cd26b6b7f> in <module>()
    ----> 1 pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([newdf.columns.to_series().map(topframe.iloc[0].to_dict()), newdf.columns])

    /opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.pyc in from_arrays(cls, arrays, sortorder, names)
        841             return Index(arrays[0], name=name)
        842 
    --> 843         cats = [Categorical.from_array(arr, ordered=True) for arr in arrays]
        844         levels = [c.categories for c in cats]
        845         labels = [c.codes for c in cats]

    /opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.pyc in from_array(cls, data, **kwargs)
        385             the unique values of `data`.
        386         """
    --> 387         return Categorical(data, **kwargs)
        388 
        389     @classmethod

    /opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.pyc in __init__(self, values, categories, ordered, name, fastpath, levels)
        286                 codes, categories = factorize(values, sort=True)
        287             except TypeError:
    --> 288                 codes, categories = factorize(values, sort=False)
        289                 if ordered:
        290                     # raise, as we don't have a sortable data structure and so

    /opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.pyc in factorize(values, sort, order, na_sentinel, size_hint)
        183     table = hash_klass(size_hint or len(vals))
        184     uniques = vec_klass()
    --> 185     labels = table.get_labels(vals, uniques, 0, na_sentinel, True)
        186 
        187     labels = com._ensure_platform_int(labels)

    pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels (pandas/hashtable.c:14033)()

    TypeError: unhashable type 'dict
```

Comment: Please post the complete traceback so that it's easier to locate where the error actually is.

Comment: I have edited @NickilMaveli

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` created by first row of second `df2` with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df2.iloc[0].to_dict())
{'2value': 5, '5value': 3, '1value': 2, '4value': 6, '3value': 2}

print (df1.columns.to_series().map(df2.iloc[0].to_dict()))
1value    2
2value    5
3value    2
4value    6
5value    3
dtype: int64

df1.columns = [df1.columns.to_series().map(df2.iloc[0].to_dict()), df1.columns]
print (df1)
           2      5      2      6      3
      1value 2value 3value 4value 5value
acity      4      3      6      2      6
bcity      2      6      6      4      1
ccity      5     11     53      6      3
dcity      5      1      4      6      3
gcity      6      4      2      7      4
```

Another solution is `rename` columns by `dict`:

```
print (df1.rename(columns=df2.iloc[0].to_dict()))
       2   5   2  6  3
acity  4   3   6  2  6
bcity  2   6   6  4  1
ccity  5  11  53  6  3
dcity  5   1   4  6  3
gcity  6   4   2  7  4

df1.columns = [df1.rename(columns=df2.iloc[0].to_dict()).columns, df1.columns]
print (df1)
           2      5      2      6      3
      1value 2value 3value 4value 5value
acity      4      3      6      2      6
bcity      2      6      6      4      1
ccity      5     11     53      6      3
dcity      5      1      4      6      3
gcity      6      4      2      7      4
```

Comment: Again, I have same problem, unhashable type dict. 
But It is dataframe when I check with type(df). @jazrael

Comment: `print (df1.columns.to_series().map(df2.iloc[0].to_dict()))` return error also? Second solution does not works too?

Comment: </code>df1.columns = [df1.columns.to_series().map(df2.iloc[0].to_dict()), df1.columns]</code>
This line gives problem, others are ok

Comment: Hmmm, it is same as `df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1.columns.to_series().map(df2.iloc[0].to_dict()), df1.columns])`

Comment: No, it's the same problem. Maybe it's problem with setting index?

Comment: problem is with sample or only with real data?

Comment: With real data.
I can't figure out what means that problem when it's not a dict at all.

Comment: are values in column nmaes unique? `print (df2.columns.is_unique)
`

Comment: Yes, they are  @jezrael

Comment: Hmm, what about your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())`

Comment: maybe only row with pandas can paste ;)

Comment: hmmm, pandas 0.18.1, it is not old

Comment: pandas: 0.18.1           
pip: 9.0.1

Comment: hmmm, are data confidental?

Comment: Yes, they are.
Can be a problem maybe because in df2 there are 3 rows, all have same value, just one is different.
I think that's not a problem, but...

Comment: I think it is not problem. One idea - `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1.columns.to_series().map(df2.i‌​loc[0].to_dict()), df1.columns])` works?

Comment: Hmmm, newest version of pandas is `0.19.2`. Is possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: Maybe, but not at this moment, tommorow, because I don't have access to amazon machine root. Thank you :)

Comment: One idea - It seems your data are categorical, so if convert to string `df1.columns = df1.columns.astype(str)` it should works.

Comment: Same againg. In this line is problem: 
finaldata.columns = [finaldata.rename(columns=topframe.iloc[0].to_dict()).columns, finaldata.columns]   @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
df.iloc[0]=df.iloc[0]+df1.iloc[0
```

Comment: Please explain your code; code-only answers are often of little use.